# ORA-00205 error during the startup of physical standby database

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, dataguard

Steps I have followed:-

1. Created a physical standby database by using `DUPLICATE TARGET DATABASE`.
2. Then checked the log gap between these two databases which was fine and in sync.
3. After that standby database closed using the shutdown abort command.
4. Then when tried to open the standby in mount mode it was showing this error.

> ORA-00205: error in identifying control file, check alert log for more info)

5. Checked the alert log where in the mentioned path there is no control file but in `initSID.ora` file, controlfile path mentioned correctly and which was different from what is showing in the alert log.

Comment: Locate the standby control file and edit the `initSID.ora` file to change `control_files` parameter.

Comment: yes I was using spfile to open the standby database. In Sp file the path was different than that of the pfile or initSID.ora file. So should I use the initSID.ora to open the standby database and another question why these path are different in these files?

Comment: The `spfile` is populated on the basis of `spfile` on primary database during the duplication. You might have created that `pfile` before the duplication.

Comment: Yes, I think I got the issue, thanks a lot. Now I am creating Pfile from sp file and manually changing the control files parameter in pfile. then opening the standby database with pfile. will it work now?

Comment: Give it a try it should work, later you can create spfile from pfile.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when your auxiliary (the clone target) database instance is started using a static init file. Smarter is to use the more dynamic spfile so the control_files parameter can be changed by the cloning procedure to where it is restored on the target.

I guess the question was: why this happened? ;-)